# $.mobile.changepage(URL) getting "Error Loading Page" with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on my first phone gap application and I am having a bit of trouble trying to navigate to other pages.

on my index html I have

```
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "nextpage.html", { 
    reload: true, 
    transition: "slide"}
);
```

but I keep getting an error loading page message appearing and then nothing happens.

From looking around online I can assume that this has something to do with nextpage.html not being found but I don't understand why it is not being found. please note I have also tried /nextpage.html and ./nextpage.html and several others without success

both pages are in the root of the www folder

can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT** 
It is worth noting that this code is working in firefox

as requested here is the javascrtipt capture from firebug

```
ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<title>Test App</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="indexPage" data-role="page">
<div class="Login">
<h1>Network</h1>
<div id="LoginForm" class="blink LoginForm">
<img src="../logo.png" alt="Logo"
style="height:50%; text-align:center;" />
<p class="event listening">Connecting to Network</p>
<p class="event received">User name</p>
<input type="text" class="event Input" id="Username"/>
<br class="event received" />
<p class="event received">Password</p>
<input type="password" class="event Input" id="Password" />
<br />
<input type="button" title="Log in" value="Log in" class="event Submit" onclick="javascript:CallLogin()" />
<p class="error" id="Invalid">Invalid login details</p>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
// app.initialize();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CallLogin() {
var CompanyID = "";
console.log('Start Function');
source:
{
console.log('Start Ajax Call');
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
crossDomain: true,
url: "http://Webservice/WebMethod",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: "{ 'Username' : '" + document.getElementById('Username').value + "','Password' : '" + document.getElementById('Password').value + "'}",
dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
success: function (data) {
if (data.d[1] == 'false') {
SetError('Invalid');
}
else {
CompanyID = data.d[0];
Set_localstorage('CompanyID', CompanyID);
console.log('CompanyID (success) = ' + get_localstorage('CompanyID'));
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "nextpage.html", { reload: true, transition: "slide"});
}
},
error: function (Error) {
console.log('CompanyID (fail) = ' + CompanyID);
console.log(Error.status);
console.log(Error.statusText);
console.log(Error.responseText);
}
});
}
console.log('End Ajax Call, CompanyID = ' + CompanyID);
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "index.html", { reload: true, transition: "slide"});`. you dont need `type`, `allowSPT` nor `changeHash`.

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage` is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0. Use the pagecontainer widget's `change()` method instead. [Read more in doc](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

Comment: I have changed as Omar recormended and when it is "index.html" nothing at all happens and when it is nextpage.html I get the same error

Comment: Probably you have in your source code some syntax error. Show your page in some developer console, e.g. Firebug.

Comment: the rest of the code is running ok though, I am using console.log to confirm that everything is running as it should be and it is only when it gets to this single line that there is an error. unless you mean there is a problem on the nextpage.html?

Comment: I have added the fire bug script as requested

Comment: you have included jQuery mobile in your page twice. You only need the jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js version.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, however it has not fixed the issue

Comment: is anyone able to help with this, even the smallest suggestion could help as I really have no idea how to proceed at this point

Comment: It turns out the problem was windows phone 7 emulator as the code runs fine on other platforms. I am unsure if this problem will carry over to a real windows 7 phone or not